# Google Sheet second part of formula doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF(INDEX('SM Responses'!$J$2:$J,MATCH($D$1&$D$2&$F5,Month('SM Responses'!$A$2:$A)&Year('SM Responses'!$A$2:$A)&'SM Responses'!$J$2:$J,0))=$F5,"Completed",IF(INDEX('SM Responses'!$J$2:$J,MATCH($E$1&$D$2&$F5,Month('SM Responses'!$A$2:$A)&Year('SM Responses'!$A$2:$A)&'SM Responses'!$J$2:$J,0))=$F5,"Completed","No"))
```

I'm trying to check if an employee submitted a form within the two month period by matching month, year, and email.

**Each individual `If/Index/Match` statement works individually**, but when I combine both it only detects results from the first `IF` statement and not from the second `IF` statement.

What's wrong with this statement? I expect the second portion of the formula works

sample google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZcSigqQhOi0MgziaIx4A0rJ45e4B2o0p6UHu71tdLE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I assume you may need `FILTER()` function. Post few sample data and then show your desired output. You may also share a sample google-sheet link.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Harun24hr Here's the sample google sheet. I am trying to check if my employees submitted checkin for within one of the two months selected. The current formula only pulls data from forms submitted in September and not detecting the forms submitted in October. I am unsure what is wrong with the formula that's preventing from checking the second IF statement if the first one is false. I appreciate your help! 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZcSigqQhOi0MgziaIx4A0rJ45e4B2o0p6UHu71tdLE/edit?usp=sharing